# Trying to add array to TS interface

Tags: typescript

I have an angular 2 project and I'm fairly new. I'm trying to create an interface that includes object arrays for things like phone numbers and emails. So for example, I want to be able to have a collections of emails and type them (personal, business, etc.). In my interface I'm doing the following for this 'emails' array.

```
[emails:{email_address:string, email_type:string, }]:any;
```

The error message I get is:

```
[ts] An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

(parameter) emails: {
    email_address: string;
    email_type: string;
}
```

I thought this message meant I needed to put quotes around 'emails' so that it was a string, but that's not right either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks all!

Here is my interface:

```
export interface IContact {
    //CONTACT INFO
      owner_id:string;
        share_id?: string;
        accepted?:boolean;
        status?:number;
        first_name?:string;
        last_name?:string;
        company?:string;
        title?:string;
        initial?:string;
        birthday?:Date;
        highschool?:string;
        college?:string;
        facebook?:string;
        linkedin?:string;
        linkedin_bus?:string;
        twitter?: string;
        google?:string;
        pinterest?:string;
        user_image?:string;
        emails: Email[];
        phones: Phone[];
        addresses: Address[];

}

    interface Email {
        email_type: string;
        email_address: string;
    }

    interface Phone {
        phone_type: string;
        phone_number: string;
    }

    interface Address {
        address_type: string;
        address: string;
        address2: string;
        city: string;
        state: string;
        zip: string;
    }
```

By the way, I call it in the controller like this:

```
  contacts: IContact;
```

Comment: There is a typo: `[emails:{email_address:string, email_type:string, }]:any;` The last comma should not be there

Comment: @John is trailing comma a typo?

Comment: Well, maybe not a typo. I just thought that you should not end an interface declaration with a comma. Maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
export interface YourInterfaceName {
  emails: Email[];
  phoneNumbers: Phone[];
}

interface Email {
  email_address: string;
  email_type: string;
}

interface Phone {
  phoneNumber: string;
  type: string;
}
```

And in your component.ts. Yo can do something like this.

```
const userData: YourInterfaceNam;

userData.emails.push({
    email_address: 's@g.com',
    email_type: 'work'
  },
  {
    email_address: 'a@g.com',
    email_type: 'home'
  }
);


userData.phoneNumbers.push({
    phoneNumber: '56316565',
    type: 'home'
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: '456132561',
    type: 'work'
  }
);

console.log(userData.emails[0].email_address); // s@g.com
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Anuradha!

Comment: Anaradha, when I try to access the array parameters in the controller it doesn't see them. So so let's say I do "contacts:IContacts;". I can get to the single properties, like "contacts.first_name". But when I try to access something like "contacts.phones.phone_number" it doesn't see the array property "phone_number". What am I missing there?

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
private test : {emails:{email_address:string, email_type:string }}[]
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you name your interface? You can use the name of the interface as a type.

```
let emails: MyEmailInterface;
```

Or the same as you have, but you are missing the array:

```
let emails: Array<{
    email_address: string;
    email_type: string;
}>;
```